# Why does calling a undefined method in import.meta throw the error (intermediate value).(...) is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am trying to call `import.meta.glob()` in an Astro/Vite project inside a utility function. A Vite plugin too calls it. And when a Vite plugin runs, Vite hasn't yet started resolving imports. As a result, the `import.meta.glob` function is getting called by Node.js and not Vite. And it's not present in the Node runtime.

But why is Node.js throwing the error `(intermediate value).glob is not a function` instead of `import.meta.glob is not a function`?

But if I run the following code, then I get the error `importMeta.glob is not a function` correctly.

```js
const importMeta = import.meta;

importMeta.glob();
```

So, why is it happening for `import.meta` only? Typically it happens when we forget to place a semicolon between a function declaration and an immediately invoked function expression. But this is definitely not the case here.

Comment: Well there's two dots, so the part before the undefined thing you're trying to call is `x.y` i.e. an intermediate value, where just `x` isn't. "intermediate" literally means `coming between two things [in time]`, and when you try to call `import.meta.glob()` then node has to first see what `import.meta` is.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ChrisG. But I think `import.meta` is special. Because if I run `const x = { y: {} }; x.y.z();`, Node is throwing `x.y.z is not a function`, it's not throwing `(intermediate value).z is not a function`.